# How can I parse the response of libcurl on IMAP?

Tags: c++, imap, libcurl

I'm using `libcurl` to fetch e-mail with IMAP.
Fetching itself is successful, but the problem is that libcurl can save the result of communication only in std::string or FILE* (as far as I have searched).

This made it difficult for me to parse the result into header, mime, and so on.

So I have searched libraries which makes parsing easier, but those are for other languages not for C/C++.

Since my project only uses C/C++, I have to use only those languages.
`VMime` is written in C/C++ but I couldn't use Vmime because it uses its own implementation on IMAP communication (which makes libcurl useless).

```
// code to save the IMAP communication result into std::string buffer

curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback);
curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
```

readBuffer is `std::string`. I want to parse the result in readBuffer into desirable data structure( ex)stl ) for easier access.

Are there good libraries for it? I have searched for a day but I couldn't find it.
Or if I can use Vmime only to parse the result, not affecting other libcurl codes that I have already finished, can you guide me how to do it?

I appreciate it in advance.

Comment: Take Curl out of the equation. Are you asking how to parse a MIME-encoded email header+body pair into some unspecified intermediate representation using C++ standard containers?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, what you summarized would be more specific.